# Appium error before setUp method called

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, appium

I am getting error when running test:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at loginTest.loginWithInvalidEmail(loginTest.java:47)
```

Everything is set up fine, except the problem is somewhere in this code.

When I am placing setUp() method code inside loginWithInvalidEmail() method, then test is running and passes successfully. But it is better not to include this method inside test method. Or maybe I should create abstract class after all?

public class loginTest {

```
AppiumDriver driver;

@Before
public AppiumDriver setUp() {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "AndroidTestDevice");

    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return driver;

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void loginWithInvalidEmail() throws Exception {

    WebElement emailLoginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("signupButton"));
    emailLoginButton.click();

    WebElement phoneNumberField = driver.findElement(By.id("phoneInput"));
    phoneNumberField.sendKeys("+33340954");

    WebElement firstNameField = driver.findElement(By.id("firstName"));
    firstNameField.sendKeys("Name");

    WebElement lastNameField = driver.findElement(By.id("lastName"));
    lastNameField.sendKeys("Name2");

    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton"));
    loginButton.click();

    WebElement invalidPhoneNumberErrorMessage = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("message")));
    assertEquals(invalidPhoneNumberErrorMessage.getText(), "The phone number is incorrect, country code is required");



}
```

}
Specs:
Running test on real Android Nexus 7, MAC OSX Yosemite, Appium v 1.4.8, test running on IntelliJ

Comment: I think that your Before method should be void and should assign instead of returning the driver

Comment: Tried that way, still same error unfortunately.
`public void setUp() throws Exception{

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "AndroidTestDevice");

            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }`

Comment: That means that your try clause has thrown and error and the driver is still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am calling setUp() and tearDown() method in each test, that way it works.